# Changing Google Maps v3 MarkerClustererPlus Title

Tags: google-maps-api-3, title, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am trying to dynamically set the cluster title, rollover text, of clustered icons.  I want the cluster count/total to be used in the rollover text.

Through `console.log` I am able to see that the `title` has been changed to that set for `var txt`.  It also works with `alert( txt )`.  The default title for a cluster is `""` and does not seem to be getting updated and stays at the default value.

Currently I am setting the title in `google.maps.event.addListener( markerClusterer, 'mouseover', function( cluster ) {})`.

I'm thinking that my code continues to execute and that might be the reason I don't see the change but I haven't been able to narrow it down.

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );

        var qs      = location.search;          
        var options = {
            zoom: 17,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControlOptions: { 
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU 
            }
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map( mapId[0], options );

        google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'idle', function() {

            var bounds = map.getBounds();

            downloadXML( ABSPATH + 'xml/maps/markers.php' + qs + '&bounds=' + bounds, function( data ) {

                var xml     = parseXml( data );
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName( "marker" );
                var markerArray = [];

                for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {

                    var attributes = getMarkerAttributes( markers[i] );
                    var marker     = createMarker( attributes );

                    // Add marker to marker array
                    markerArray.push(marker);

                }

                // Define the marker clusterer
                var clusterOptions = { 
                    zoomOnClick: false,
                    gridSize: 1
                }

                var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer( map, markerArray, clusterOptions );

                // Listen for a cluster to be clicked
                google.maps.event.addListener( markerClusterer, 'clusterclick', function( cluster ) {
                    combineInfoWindows( cluster );              
                });

                // Listen for a cluster to be hovered and set title
                google.maps.event.addListener( markerClusterer, 'mouseover', function( cluster ) {
                    var txt = 'There are ' + cluster.getSize() + ' properties at this location.';
                    //alert( txt );
                    console.log( cluster );
                    markerClusterer.setTitle( txt );
                });

            }); // downloadXML

        }); // google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'idle', ... )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**EDIT: 1**

I have a solution based on the suggested solution by *Rick*.

I have modified the onAdd method.

```
/**
 * Adds the icon to the DOM.
 */
ClusterIcon.prototype.onAdd = function () {
  var cClusterIcon = this;

// MY CHANGES - START
this.cluster_.markerClusterer_.title_ = 'There are ' + this.cluster_.getSize() + ' properties at this location.';
// MY CHANGES - END

  this.div_ = document.createElement("div");
  if (this.visible_) {
    this.show();
  }

...

};
```

**EDIT: 2 - FINAL SOLUTION**

Moved changes to `show` method versus previous `onAdd` method as *Rick* had suggested.  Change is made in a file outside of the original source file for MarkerClustererPlus.

```
/**
 * Positions and shows the icon.
 */
ClusterIcon.prototype.show = function () {
  if (this.div_) {
    var pos = this.getPosFromLatLng_(this.center_);
    this.div_.style.cssText = this.createCss(pos);
    if (this.cluster_.printable_) {
     // (Would like to use "width: inherit;" below, but doesn't work with MSIE)
     this.div_.innerHTML = "<img src='" + this.url_ + "'><div style='position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: " + this.width_ + "px;'>" + this.sums_.text + "</div>";
    } else {
     this.div_.innerHTML = this.sums_.text;
    }
    //this.div_.title = this.cluster_.getMarkerClusterer().getTitle();
    // MY SOLUTION BELOW
    this.div_.title = 'There are ' + this.cluster_.getSize() + ' properties at this location.';
    this.div_.style.display = "";
  }
  this.visible_ = true;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [this](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) for clustering markers? Did you extend it to make your own setTitle function? If not,  You'll have to make your own label. It's not actually a marker per se.

Edit: Didn't know this existed.

The cluster icons just pull the title from the MCOptions. I don't see where ClusterIcon or Cluster has a setTitle function, so I'd think the best bet would be overriding the ClusterIcon show prototype yourself and setting it there.

```
> ClusterIcon.prototype.show =
> function () {   if (this.div_) {
>     var pos = this.getPosFromLatLng_(this.center_);
>     this.div_.style.cssText = this.createCss(pos);
>     if (this.cluster_.printable_) {
>       // (Would like to use "width: inherit;" below, but doesn't work with MSIE)
>       this.div_.innerHTML = "<img src='" + this.url_ + "'><div style='position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: " + this.width_
> + "px;'>" + this.sums_.text + "</div>";
>     } else {
>       this.div_.innerHTML = this.sums_.text;
>     }
>     this.div_.title = **** Your stuff here ***
>     this.div_.style.display = "";   }   this.visible_ = true; };
```

Comment: I am not currently using `this` or my own setTitle function.  I should also clarify that I'm using MarkerClusterPlus as is stated in the title.  Your link is to MarkerClusterer.  [MarkerClustererPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html#ClusterIconInfo) has `setTitle` and `getTitle` methods.

Comment: See my edit. The setTitle/getTitle are for the MarkerClusterer itself, not the Cluster or ClusterIcon.

Comment: Yes.  I'm trying a couple solutions here including your edit.

Comment: As much as I dig this roll-up the sleeves approach, you guys have to realize that you are essentially branching the utility library with this kind of code. It's not really a safe path to go forward, and it will mean you have work to do as each version is released, but I still respect the adventurous approach. Of course, if this works and you like it, you could always look into merging your code into the library and adding a true `Cluster.setTitle` function. Bust of luck -

Comment: I have something that works.  Though I am no javascript ninja and this feels a little dirty.  This solution is above as the first edit to my post.

Comment: Yes, this is down and dirty, essentially a hack, but it does work. And if it works for you, it might be just what you need. Myself, I might put this in place for the near-term, but I wouldn't go forward with this. And I have nothing but respect for Rick - very quick and it is a solution. I guess just understand what you are doing and decide if you are comfortable. You can always change it later, I guess. Just trying to help and share my opinion -

Comment: I see your point, but Clusters seem too volatile for a single setTitle function to really matter (or I'd think the class would have one since it's got some extended functionality over the original Marker Clusterer). Either way, you're going to have to 'branch' the library to handle this functionality. I don't see why overriding the Cluster's show function would be considered a bad solution.

Comment: On a side note, I was advocating redefining the prototype in another source file not replacing the actual function in the library source.

Comment: @Rick Agreed on the single `setTitle`; that's a flaw in the library. And I'm not trying to start a debate, I just worry that if the library author(s) make changes down in the guts of the code, it could collide with your fix and cause problems later, even if it's outside of the library. At any rate, your solution is great. Would you be interested in offering your solution (maybe with some polish) as an upgrade to the library? Then it helps everyone. +1 your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to assign the `mouseover` event listener (where you set the title) to a `MarkerClusterer`, but to define a `mouseover` listener, you have to pass a `Cluster`.

There is a `MarkerClusterer.getClusters()` function that will return an `Array` of the `Cluster` instances. You want to loop over that `Array` and pass an instance of `Cluster` to your `mouseover` event listeners. If you check the [reference doc](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/docs/reference.html) and scroll down to the `MarkerClusterer` **Events** section of the doc, the row for `mouseover` defines the **Argument** to be:

```
c:Cluster
```

Which is in contrast to events like `clusteringbegin` and `clusteringend`, which define the **Argument** to be:

```
mc:MarkerClusterer
```

Having said all that, I'm not sure there is an easy way to set the title for each `Cluster`. That class does not have a `setTitle` function. The `setTitle` on the `MarkerClusterer` just applies the title to **all** of the `Cluster` instances. And I've double checked in JavaScript; there is no `setTitle` function on the `Cluster` class. Your best option right now seems to be to dynamically create the content you want to display within the `mouseover` handler for each `Cluster`. You could create an [InfoBox](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#InfoBox) and then close it on a `Cluster` `mouseoet` event. Not the simplest solution ever, but it will get you where you want to be.

Comment: I am trying some things on my map; I will see if I can figure out something straightforward -

Comment: The `setTitle` on the `MarkerClusterer` just applies the title to **all** of the `Cluster` instances. And I've double checked in JavaScript; there is no `setTitle` function on the `Cluster` class. Your best option right now seems to be to dynamically create the content you want to display within the `mouseover` handler for each `Cluster`. You could create an [InfoBox](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#InfoBox) and then close it on a `Cluster` `mouseoet` event. Not the simplest solution ever, but it will get you where you want to be.

Comment: Added the info in my previous comment to the answer text, for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it ranked high on Google for my search. Anyway, here is what I did thanks to tips from this page:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'mouseover', function (c) {
    if(c.clusterIcon_.div_){
        c.clusterIcon_.div_.title =  c.getSize() + ' businesses in this area';
    }
});
```

I can't guarantee it will be compatible with future versions of MarkerClusterer Plus since I'm using "private" properties clusterIcon_ and div_.

Comment: I'll add that the proper way to do this is probably to use MarkerClusterer Plus' "calculator" functionality. I didn't have time to really look into it.